# get EditText value from onclick function

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How do I get the value of my EditText that the user typed in from the function that was called when the onClick was pressed. I tried this below but its not working. Thanks for the help.

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/myEditT" />

<Button android:text="MY BUTTON" android:onClick="GetThis" />
```

---

```
public void GetThis(View view) {


    EditText x = (EditText)parentView.findViewById( R.id.myEditT);

    // alert the x variable

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditT);
String your_text = x.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML,

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/myEditT"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

In Java,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(
        public void onClick(View v){
            String value = edtText.getText().toString();
        }
    )); 
}
```

Comment: thanks but its not working  - it wont  see  "edtText"

Comment: @Hello-World, for you it is x.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetThis(View view) {
    EditText x = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditT);
    String edittextvalue = x.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - but there is still an issue. The x comes back as null . Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText x;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml);
    x = (EditText)parentView.findViewById( R.id.myEditT);
    public void GetThis(View view) {
    String s=x.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807186/null-pointer-exception-getting-edittext-value

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText x = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditT);

public void GetThis(View view) {
    String getEditTextValue = x.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getEditTextValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```